# What are the scaling limits of Dask.distributed?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, dask

Are there any anecdotal cases of [Dask.distributed](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) deployments with hundreds of worker nodes?  Is distributed meant to scale to a cluster of this size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes

The largest Dask.distributed cluster I've seen is around one thousand nodes.  We could theoretically go larger, but not by a huge amount.

The current limit is that the scheduler incurs around a 200 microsecond overhead per task.  This translates to about 5000 tasks per second.  If each of your tasks take around one second then the scheduler can saturate around 5000 cores.

Historically we ran into other limitations like open file handle limits and such.  These have all been cleaned up to the scale that we've seen (1000 nodes) and generally things are fine on Linux or OSX.  Dask schedulers on Windows stop scaling in the low hundreds of nodes (though you can use a Linux scheduler with Windows workers).  I would not be surprised to see other issues pop up as we scale out to 10k nodes.

In short, you probably don't want to use Dask to replace MPI workloads on your million core Big Iron SuperComputer or at Google Scale.  Otherwise you're probably fine.

Comment: "Dask *on Windows* stops scaling in the low hundreds of nodes" :(

Comment: You can use a Linux scheduler with Windows workers.  If you can launch a virtual machine on one of your Windows machines then you'll be fine up into the thousands.

Comment: But what kind of hardware do you need to run the scheduler at scale?